# tabletop_objects stack installation

Tags: ros, tabletop-object-detector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I need to work with the tabletop_objects stack. I was wondering if someone could help me with the following:

1. Is tabletop_objects ready to use with ROS Fuerte or should I use ROS Electric ?
2. Has anyone used the tabletop_objects detector with Kinect input and without the manipulation ?

- 

Thanks
Aditya

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49564/tabletop_objects-stack-installation/) by [adigoil](https://answers.ros.org/users/2271/adigoil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-12-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think it's best to create one post per question. Regarding usability of tabletop_object_perception in Fuerte: sure. Just install it with

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-pr2-object-manipulation
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0